# String Replace With Parameter Value Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to populate a text area with a formatted letter, which comes from a text file. This text file contains objects like `{{client.name}}` and `{{client.address}}`, which I would like to replace with the value of the specific client's attribute. Here is the code I have this far,

```
$scope.loadFlyer = function() {
    $http.get("/assets/clientwelcome.txt").then(function(res){
        $scope.flyerdescription = res.data;
        $scope.flyerdescription = $scope.flyerdescription.replace(/{{client.name}}/g, $scope.client.name); 
  });
};
```

Where previously I had called the data from the client's table:

```
myApp.controller('ClientCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
$scope.clients = [];
$http.get('/client').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.clients = data;
    if (data == "") {
        $scope.clients = [];
    }
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Ops: could not get any data");
});
```

And this is the field that I am trying to populate:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="flyer-description">Description</label>
    <textarea style="height:400px" class="form-control" id="flyer-description" ng-model="flyerdescription"></textarea>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, no replacing is done. I've tried to format the replace as I have seen in the javascript documents, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Editted* per discussion below

You have a list of clients that looks like [{name: 'Hank Aaron'}, {name: 'Sandy Koufax'}, {name: 'Bo Jackson'}], and a template string, that contains a value: '{{client.name}}', that you want to replace with a name from your clients list.

```
myApp.controller('ClientCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.clients = [];
    $http.get('/client').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.clients = data;
        if (data == "") {
            $scope.clients = [];
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Ops: could not get any data");
    });

    $scope.loadFlyer = function() {
        $http.get("/assets/clientwelcome.txt").then(function(res){
            $scope.flyerdescription = res.data;
            $scope.descriptions = [];
            for(var i=0; i<$scope.clients.length; i++){
                $scope.descriptions[i].push($scope.flyerdescription.replace(/{{client.name}}/g,$scope.clients[i].name));
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

and in your HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div ng-repeat="description in descriptions">
        <label class="control-label" for="flyer-description">Description</label>
        <textarea style="height:400px" class="form-control" id="flyer-description" ng-model="description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, the other thread wasn't receiving much feedback and I felt could be replaced. If $scope.flyerdescription is not holding a string, how would I be able to replace those fields with the JSON data otherwise ?

Comment: Agh, I realized my mistake, $scope.flyerdescription.replace(.....) just returns the value of your string with the replacements made, it does not modify the original. What you need to do is capture it, by calling $scope.flyerdescription = $scope.flyerdescription.replace(/{{client.name}}/g, $scope.client.name); careful with the strings in your replace call, you don't need apostrophes for regex

Comment: Okay, I will try momentarily

Comment: I tried, no avail -- I've updated my post with the new code

Comment: Hmmm, can you confirm $scope.flyerdescription holds the data from your text file? You can call console.log($scope.flyerdescription), and open f+12 in your browser and navigate to the console. It should print out the contents of your text file

Comment: Yes, it did print out contents of txt file

Comment: Ooo jackpot, ok. So you need to define $scope.client = {name: '<client-name>', ....etc fields}, before its being used in your http callback

Comment: Will that counteract my $scope.client previously defined?

Comment: Also, I am confused by your syntax. When do <> come into play?

Comment: That's the issue - when you are trying to replace, the value is undefined at that point, you can confirm by calling console.log($scope.client) in your http callback, I would expect it to print undefined to your console. Where and when are you setting $scope.client?

Comment: Please see second code box in original post. That is the beginning of the controller. I am only working in one controller

Comment: Apologies, I use <stuff_here> to indicate fill in your own data conceptually. This is more clear now, so you have an array of clients you want to produce this description for. Just a second I'll update my answer to better reflect your goal

Comment: Have you updated the answer, it still shows to me as answered 16 hours ago.

Comment: Updated to better reflect what it seems like you are trying to do

Comment: Unfortunately, tried the code again and to no avail

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="validationCtrl"  class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="flyer-description">Description</label>
    <textarea style="height:100px" class="form-control" id="flyer-description" ng-model="stringname
"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
//This is controller
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);
app.controller('validationCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.stringname = 'angular123456 test demo';
    $scope.stringname = $scope.stringname.replace('test', "");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```